# How to make a select with increasing and decreasing order in ajax and php?

Tags: javascript, php, html, sql, ajax

Good morning, sorry for my ignorance, but I am not able to make a select to order the products in a table, I am changing an Ajax Product Filters in PHP, I made the select code in html, then I did the basics to receive the data in php and give the order to be shown in sql, but it is not working ... Could you help me in this matter? Below is the code ...

```html
<html>
<div class="list-group">
    <form method="GET" name="form1">
    <p class="text" align="left">  <h3>Ordenar por:</h3>
        <select name="ordenar" onchange="this.form.submit()">
            <option value="nenhum"  Selected> </option>
            <option value="pasc" > Preço Ascendente </option>
            <option value="pdesc" > Preço Descendente </option>
        </select>
    </p> 
    </form> 
</div>


<?php

//fetch_data.php

if(!isset($_GET["ordenar"])){
$ordenar="pasc";
}
else{
$ordenar=$_GET["ordenar"];
}


if($ordenar=='pasc'){
$ordenapor="product_price asc";
}
if($ordenar=='pdesc'){
$ordenapor="product_price desc";
}

include('BD_Connect.php');      
        
if(isset($_POST["action"]))
{
        
    $query = "SELECT*FROM produto WHERE product_status = '1' order by $ordenapor";
    
    if(isset($_POST["minimum_price"], $_POST["maximum_price"]) && !empty($_POST["minimum_price"]) && !empty($_POST["maximum_price"]))
    {
        $query .= " AND product_price BETWEEN '".$_POST["minimum_price"]."' AND '".$_POST["maximum_price"]."' ";
    }
    if(isset($_POST["brand"]))
    {
        $brand_filter = implode("','", $_POST["brand"]);
        $query .= " AND product_brand IN('".$brand_filter."') ";
    }
    
    
    if(isset($_POST["ram"]))
    {
        $ram_filter = implode("','", $_POST["ram"]);
        $query .= " AND product_ram IN('".$ram_filter."') ";
    }
    if(isset($_POST["storage"]))
    {
        $storage_filter = implode("','", $_POST["storage"]);
        $query .= " AND product_storage IN('".$storage_filter."') ";
    }

    $statement = $connect->prepare($query);
    $statement->execute();
    $result = $statement->fetchAll();
    $total_row = $statement->rowCount();
    $output = '';
    if($total_row > 0)
    {
        foreach($result as $row)
        {
            $output .= '
            <div class="col-sm-4 col-lg-3 col-md-3">
                <div style="border:1px solid #ccc; border-radius:5px; padding:16px; margin-bottom:16px; height:450px;">
                    <img src="image/'. $row['product_image'] .'" alt="" class="img-responsive" >
                    <p align="center"><strong><a href="#">'. $row['product_name'] .'</a></strong></p>
                    <h4 style="text-align:center;" class="text-danger" >'. $row['product_price'] .'</h4>
                    <p>Camera : '. $row['product_camera'].' MP<br />
                    Brand : '. $row['product_brand'] .' <br />
                    RAM : '. $row['product_ram'] .' GB<br />
                    Storage : '. $row['product_storage'] .' GB </p>
                </div>

            </div>
            ';
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $output = '<h3>No Data Found</h3>';
    }
    echo $output;
}

?>
</html>
```

```html
<?php 

//index.php

include('BD_Connect.php');
?>


<html lang="en">

<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <title>Product filter in php</title>

    <script src="jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link href = "css/jquery-ui.css" rel = "stylesheet">
    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
    <!-- Page Content -->
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <br />
            <h2 align="center">Ajax Product Filters in PHP</h2>
            <br />
            <div class="col-md-3">        

                <div class="list-group">
                    <h3>Price</h3>
                    <input type="hidden" id="hidden_minimum_price" value="0" />
                    <input type="hidden" id="hidden_maximum_price" value="1500" />
                    <p id="price_show">50 - 1500</p>
                    <div id="price_range"></div>
                </div>  
                
                <div class="list-group">
                    <h3>Brand</h3>
                    <div style="height: 180px; overflow-y: auto; overflow-x: hidden;">
                    <?php

                    $query = "SELECT DISTINCT(product_brand),product_id FROM produto WHERE product_status = '1' ORDER BY product_id DESC;";
                    $statement = $connect->prepare($query);
                    $statement->execute();
                    $result = $statement->fetchAll();
                    foreach($result as $row)
                    {
                    ?>
                    <div class="list-group-item checkbox">
                        <label><input type="checkbox" class="common_selector brand" value="<?php echo $row['product_brand']; ?>"  > <?php echo $row['product_brand']; ?></label>
                    </div>
                    <?php
                    }

                    ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
                

                <div class="list-group">
                    <h3>RAM</h3>
                    <?php

                    $query = "
                    SELECT DISTINCT(product_ram) FROM produto WHERE product_status = '1' ORDER BY product_ram DESC;
                    ";
                    $statement = $connect->prepare($query);
                    $statement->execute();
                    $result = $statement->fetchAll();
                    foreach($result as $row)
                    {
                    ?>
                    <div class="list-group-item checkbox">
                        <label><input type="checkbox" class="common_selector ram" value="<?php echo $row['product_ram']; ?>" > <?php echo $row['product_ram']; ?> GB</label>
                    </div>
                    <?php    
                    }

                    ?>
                </div>
                
                <div class="list-group">
                    <h3>Internal Storage</h3>
                    <?php
                    $query = "
                    SELECT DISTINCT(product_storage) FROM produto WHERE product_status = '1' ORDER BY product_storage DESC;
                    ";
                    $statement = $connect->prepare($query);
                    $statement->execute();
                    $result = $statement->fetchAll();
                    foreach($result as $row)
                    {
                    ?>
                    <div class="list-group-item checkbox">
                        <label><input type="checkbox" class="common_selector storage" value="<?php echo $row['product_storage']; ?>"  > <?php echo $row['product_storage']; ?> GB</label>
                    </div>
                    <?php
                    }
                    ?>  
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-9">
                <br />
                <div class="row filter_data">

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
<style>
#loading
{
    text-align:center; 
    background: url('loader.gif') no-repeat center; 
    height: 150px;
}
</style>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

    filter_data();

    function filter_data()
    {
        $('.filter_data').html('<div id="loading" style="" ></div>');
        var action = 'fetch_data';
        var minimum_price = $('#hidden_minimum_price').val();
        var maximum_price = $('#hidden_maximum_price').val();
        var brand = get_filter('brand');
        var ram = get_filter('ram');
        var storage = get_filter('storage');
        $.ajax({
            url:"fetch_data.php",
            method:"POST",
            data:{action:action, minimum_price:minimum_price, maximum_price:maximum_price, brand:brand, ram:ram, storage:storage},
            success:function(data){
                $('.filter_data').html(data);
            }
        });
    }

    function get_filter(class_name)
    {
        var filter = [];
        $('.'+class_name+':checked').each(function(){
            filter.push($(this).val());
        });
        return filter;
    }

    $('.common_selector').click(function(){
        filter_data();
    });

    $('#price_range').slider({
        range:true,
        min:50,
        max:1500,
        values:[50, 1500],
        step:10,
        stop:function(event, ui)
        {
            $('#price_show').html(ui.values[0] + ' - ' + ui.values[1]);
            $('#hidden_minimum_price').val(ui.values[0]);
            $('#hidden_maximum_price').val(ui.values[1]);
            filter_data();
        }
    });

});

</script>


</body>

</html>
```

```html
<?php 

//database_connection.php

$connect = new PDO("mysql:host=remotemysql.com;dbname=D6DVgw31iE", "D6DVgw31iE", "PQkTajbCkv");


?>
```

Comment: You are very likely getting SQL errors. Echo the `$query` before the prepare to see how the statement looks. Where you build the query with `order by $ordenapor`, the next 4 `if` conditions after that are appending `AND` filters that should be part of the `WHERE` clause. The `order by $ordenapor` should be the _last portion_ to append before the `prepare`. **Side note**, you are wide-open to SQL injection. As you are using prepare, use parameterized statements to avoid trouble. (it also cleans up the SQL some, less quoting involved)

Comment: Sorry, I didn't quite understand what you meant by this: "the next 4 if conditions after that are appending AND filters that should be part of the WHERE clause." @PaulT.

Comment: Where you make the query string `SELECT * FROM produto WHERE product_status = '1' order by $ordenapor`, there are 4 `if`'s on `minimum_price`, `brand`, `ram', and `storage` after that line.

Comment: Thank you bro, I will see how to place the order, I had not noticed this issue, thank you a lot sir. @PaulT.

Comment: Replace $ statement = $ connect-> prepare ($ query); for $ statement = $ connect-> prepare ($ query. "order by $ ordenapor"); helped a little bit, it just doesn't work in descending order. I will try to modify it so that it works, thank you XD